# How do I delete the first n lines of an ascii file using shell commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have multiple files that contain ascii text information in the first 5-10 lines, followed by well-tabulated matrix information.  In a shell script, I want to remove these first few lines of text so that I can use the pure matrix information in another program.  How can I use bash shell commands to do this?

If it's any help, I'm using RedHat and an Ubuntu linux systems.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

As long as the file is not a symlink or hardlink, you can use sed, tail, or awk. Example below.

```
$ cat t.txt
12
34
56
78
90
```

### sed

```
$ sed -e '1,3d' < t.txt
78
90
```

You can also use sed in-place without a temp file: `sed -i -e 1,3d yourfile`. This won't echo anything, it will just modify the file in-place. If you don't need to pipe the result to another command, this is easier.

### tail

```
$ tail -n +4 t.txt
78
90
```

### awk

```
$ awk 'NR > 3 { print }' < t.txt
78
90
```

Comment: You can also use sed in-place without a temp file: `sed -i -e 1,3d yourfile`. This won't echo anything, it will just modify the file in-place. If you don't need to pipe the result to another command, this is easier.

Comment: As long as the file is not a symlink or hardlink.

Comment: @jw013 What is the symlink limitation about? Sed? Awk? Tail? All of them?

Comment: @Svetlana `sed -i` specifically.  Most implementations just delete the file and replace it with a new one, which doesn't work for links since you end up leaving the original at its other location.

Comment: how about explaining what '1,3d', +4, et.c. means? The question was for n lines, but you didn't tell what n is (as apparently n is 2 in your examples, though it's not obvious for a noob what to change in order to change n)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams what would the command look like if I need to remove a variable number of lines. e.g. sed -i -e "1,${n}d" yourfile. what is the correct syntax to remove n number of lines

Comment: This uses a temp file so not very useful for a 100% util disk space. Would be interesting to have a solution that does this literally "in-place".

Comment: @Shai yes `sed` doesn't do it in-place at all, it creates a temp file.

Comment: You can also do a sed -e '1,3d' t.txt

Comment: Dont try on 'live' (log) files as this will replace the actual file with truncated file.

Comment: For the `tail` solution, if you're trying to get the last 2 lines you can do `tail -n -2 t.txt`.

Answer (score 54):

`sed -i '1,3d' file.txt`

This deletes first 3 line from file.txt.

Comment: I need to remove the 50 first lines  from a 10GB+ text file. Even if it's supposed to work "in-place", this command still takes a few minutes. Is there any really fast alternative ?

Comment: @Sébastien if you only have to remove the 50 first lines, open the file in a text editor, select the 50 first lines and delete them maybe? It took 17 seconds to remove the 8 473 386 first lines of a 7GB+ text files with this command, I have to admit I find it quite fast.

Comment: If you have a 10GB log file and only ~1GB left of space, this solution won't work as creates a tmp file

Answer (score 9):

If the tabulated lines are the ones that have a tab character:

```
grep '␉' <input_file >output_file
```

(`␉` being a literal tab character) or equivalently

```
sed -n '/␉/p' <input_file >output_file
```

In a bash/ksh/zsh script, you can write `$'\t'` for a tab, e.g. `grep $'\t'` or `sed -n $'/\t/p'`.

If you want to eliminate 10 lines at the beginning of the file:

```
tail -n +11 <input_file >output_file
```

(note that it's `+11` to eliminate 10 lines, because `+11` means “start from line 11” and tail numbers lines from 1) or

```
sed '1,10d' <input_file >output_file
```

On Linux, you can take advantage of GNU sed's `-i` option to modify files in place:

```
sed -i -n '/\t/p' *.txt
```

Or you can use a shell loop and temporary files:

```
for x in *.txt; do
  tail -n +11 <"$x" >"$x.tmp"
  mv "$x.tmp" "$x"
done
```

Or if you don't want to modify the files in place, but instead give them a different name:

```
for x in *.txt; do
  tail -n +11 <"$x" >"${x%.txt}.data"
done
```

Comment: "tabulated" usually means "pretty-printed in a table", not "indented with tab characters".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know. The pretty-printed table sometimes uses tab characters, that's easier to spot than aligned columns. Of course, if Paul gave a sample input, I could give a better matcher.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -s -c '1d5|x' file
```

1. `1` move to first line
2. `5` select 5 lines
3. `d` delete
4. `x` save and close

Comment: This also creates .swp file, so if you are low on disk space, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

### By percentage

Using `bash`, to clean up a file using a percentage number instead of an absolute number of lines:

```bsh
sed -i -e 1,$( printf  "$((`cat php_errors.log | wc -l` * 75 /100 ))" )d php_errors.log
```

Watch out because that command can be destructive since it deletes content in-place, without creating a copy.

It deletes the first 75% of lines from the mentioned file.

Comment: This is good, but perhaps move file name out as a variable would be better

Comment: Blazing fast tho!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
# deletes first line
echo "a\nb" | sed '1d' 

# read list.txt and write list.csv without first line
cat list.txt | sed '1d' > list.csv
```

Other useful commands:

```
# finds first character (pipe|)
grep '^|' 

# deletes pipe
sed 's/|//g'  

# deletes space
sed 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score -1):

i created a small script which will delete everything from the **/var/log/messages** except last 4 lines.

**# cat remove-range-of-lines.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#print total line number
line_count=`awk 'END{print NR}' /var/log/messages`

#exclude last 4 lines
remove_line=`expr $line_count - 4`

#remove everything except last 4 lines
sed -i '1,'$remove_line'd' /var/log/messages
```

using this script we can always keep latest entry in the **/var/log/messages** based on our requirement

if you want to keep last 10000 entries in the **/var/log/messages** below is the modified script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#print total line number
line_count=`awk 'END{print NR}' /var/log/messages`

#exclude last 10000 lines
remove_line=`expr $line_count - 10000`

#remove everything except last 10000 lines
sed -i '1,'$remove_line'd' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. The issue is to remove the first `n` lines, not to keep the last `n` lines.