# How to delete number of lines from file repetitively

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed

I've read [How do I delete the first n lines of an ascii file using shell commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands), it is helpful. However I've a file something as below (please consider 2 columns as 2 different files):

```
1 4
1 4
1 4
1 4
1 4
3 5
3 5
3 5
3 5
3 5
7 5
7 5
7 5
7 5
7 5
```

I need to delete line 2-5 then 7-10 and so on (Valid outputs are 1, 3, 7 and 4, 5, 5).

I know number of lines for which pattern (number) repeats. However I don't know if everytime it would follow same pattern for e.g. here its 1, 3, 7 next file can have 4, 6, 1 or 4, 5, 5 so I need to make it number of lines based than grepping the values.

Can anyone give me a pointer how would I delete lines repetitively?

Comment: is there a possibility that your file may contain more than 15 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `uniq`.

Or, from the comments:

```
sed '2,5d;7,10d;12,$d'
```

Comment: Thanks however `uniq` fails in case of 4, 5, 5 (all repeated 5 times each). This is why I was looking for number of lines based solution

Comment: @wisemonkey, I guess I don't properly understand the question.  Maybe you should add more examples or try describing it another way.

Comment: My bad, please have a look at modified question. Hopefully second sequence makes it easier (for now I'm going to use `uniq` and then add extra entry if required)

Comment: @wisemonkey, is `sed '2,5d;7,10d;12,$d'` what you're looking for?

Comment: exactly but I didn't know I can cascade them like that, awesome thanks a lot :D

Comment: Note that you can use `sed` to look for the lines if you kwon the pattern, or even use something like `grep pattern file` to select just what you are looking for. More flexible tools in that line include Perl and Python (some programming required for funkier stuff).

Comment: @vonbrand: I generally use Perl but I'm not looking for any pattern, its basically oversampled output of my design block I want to remove unnecessary samples.

Comment: I wanted to know if I can make `sed` anymore generic? for e.g. I don't know length of file, and I want to change number of samples to be deleted from 4 to 7 (I know I probably need to read a tutorial about `sed` however I want to know if I can do it and then link to tutorial if possible)

Comment: For a more generic `sed` expression using branching try `sed -n ':a;N;N;N;N;P;d;ba' file`. See http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-two/ for example

Answer (score 0):

If what you are really asking is output every nth line of a file:

```
cat file | perl -ne '$. % 5 or print'
```

Possibly:

```
cat file | perl -ne '($.-1) % 5 or print'
```

Answer (score -1):

use following command

```
cat filename | sort | uniq > filename2
```

Comment: How does `sort` and `uniq` help in this case? Your solution would fail on the given example itself. Since the output is expected to be `4,5,5`, however, `uniq` would eliminate the second 5.

Comment: @darnir Code tested on the given file and the output is as expected i.e. `1 4  
3 5  
7 5`