# grep -v: How to exclude only the first (or last) N lines that match?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Sometimes there are a few really annoying lines in otherwise tabular data like

```
column name | other column name
-------------------------------
```

I generally prefer removing garbage lines that shouldn't be there by `grep -v` ing a reasonably unique string, but the problem with that approach is that if the reasonably unique string appears in the data by accident that's a serious problem.

Is there a way to limit the number of lines that `grep -v` can remove (say to 1)? For bonus points, is there a way to count the number of lines from the end without resorting to `<some command> | tac | grep -v <some stuff> | tac` ?

Comment: how about `awk 'NR>2'` ?

Comment: looking for something ``cat a.txt | sed -e '1,2d' | tac | sed -e '1,1d' | tac`` where ``1,2d`` removes 1st two lines which is column name and hyphen row and ``1,1d`` removes the result count row. And check it out in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands

Comment: `grep` unfortunately can not do it.  The closest option would be to limit the number of lines shown before you ignore them: `grep -v -m 10` would show the first 10 matches and ignore the rest.

Comment: You can do both of these using the [POSIX-specified predecessor to `vi` known as `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  If you include example input output I'll elucidate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` provides a simpler way:

```
... |  sed '/some stuff/ {N; s/^.*\n//; :p; N; $q; bp}' | ...
```

This way you delete first occurrence.

If you want more:

```
sed '1 {h; s/.*/iiii/; x}; /some stuff/ {x; s/^i//; x; td; b; :d; d}'
```

, where count of `i` is count of occurrences (one or more, not zero).

#### Multi-line Explanation

```
sed '1 {
    # Save first line in hold buffer, put `i`s to main buffer, swap buffers
    h
    s/^.*$/iiii/
    x
}

# For regexp what we finding
/some stuff/ {
    # Remove one `i` from hold buffer
    x
    s/i//
    x
    # If successful, there was `i`. Jump to `:d`, delete line
    td
    # If not, process next line (print others).
    b
    :d
    d
}'
```

#### In addition

Probably, this variant will work faster, 'cos it reads all rest lines and print them in one time

```
sed '1 {h; s/.*/ii/; x}; /a/ {x; s/i//; x; td; :print_all; N; $q; bprint_all; :d; d}'
```

#### As result

You can put this code into your `.bashrc` (or config of your shell, if it is other):

```
dtrash() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        cat
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        sed "/$1/ {N; s/^.*\n//; :p; N; \$q; bp}"
    else
        count=""
        for i in $(seq $1)
        do
            count="${count}i"
        done
        sed "1 {h; s/.*/$count/; x}; /$2/ {x; s/i//; x; td; :print_all; N; \$q; bprint_all; :d; d}"

    fi
}
```

And use it this way:

```
# Remove first occurrence
cat file | dtrash 'stuff' 
# Remove four occurrences
cat file | dtrash 4 'stuff'
# Don't modify
cat file | dtrash
```

Comment: This is GNU-Sed specific.  To use Sed labels and branching portably in a one-liner, use e.g. `sed -e '/some stuff/ {N; s/^.*\n//; :p' -e 'N; $q; bp' -e '}'`  In other words you cannot *portably* include anything after a label name within the same argument.  (You can also embed a newline, or put the Sed script in a file and use `sed -f`, but this is the clean portable one-liner branching approach.)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `awk` to ignore the first *n* lines that match (e.g. assuming you wanted to remove only the 1st and 2nd match from the file):

```
n=2
awk -v c=$n '/PATTERN/ && i++ < c {next};1' infile
```

---

To ignore the last *n* lines that match:

```
awk -v c=${lasttoprint} '!(/PATTERN/ && NR > c)' infile
```

where `${lasttoprint}` is the line number of the `n`th+1 to last match in your file. There are various ways to get that line no. (e.g. print only the line number for each match via tools like `sed`/`awk`, then `tail | head` to extract it)... here's one way with `gnu awk`:

```
n=2
lasttoprint=$(gawk -v c=$((n+1)) '/PATTERN/{x[NR]};
END{asorti(x,z,"@ind_num_desc");{print z[c]}}' infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reduce the chances of filtering out your data by using a more accurate grep command. For example:

```
grep -v -F -x 'str1'
```

For lines that are *exatctly* str1. Or maybe:

```
grep -v '^str1.*str2$'
```

For lines that start with 'str1' and end with 'str2'.

Comment: `-F` means "fixed string", ie. don't interpret this as a regexp.  For matching the *line* exactly, you also need `-x`.

Comment: Quite right. Thanks! I edited the answer to add this.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you might have to use awk.

The simple way I know is this:

```
cat file | awk '{ $1=""; print}'
```

You can skip multiple columns too:

```
cat file | awk '{ $1=$2=$3=""; print}'
```

If you want to skip the last column and you're not sure how much columns you will have:

```
cat file | awk '{ $NF=""; print}'
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 (GNU bash, version 4.3.48)

Best.

Comment: Note that you don't need to `cat` a file to `awk`; just provide it as command-line argument, it can read files completely on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use bashs own utilities:

```
count=1
found=0
cat execute-commons-fileupload.sh | while read line
do 
   if [[ $line == *"myPattern"* ]]
   then 
      if [ $found -eq $count ]
      then 
         echo "$line"
      else 
         found=$(($found+1))
      fi
   else 
     echo "$line"
   fi
done
```

By setting count, you can change the count of occurences of your pattern which you want to remove.

For me personally, this seems to be easier extendable, since you can easily add other conditions to the `if` statement (but this might be caused by my marginal knowledge of sed).

Comment: Please note that while it _is_ possible to perform text processing using shell `read` loops, it is quite inefficient when compared to solutions involving `awk`, for example, which has a rather powerful syntax for complex text and string manipulation tasks (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for an overview on why using a shell loop is considered bad practice).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For some use cases, using shell `read` loops is sufficiently fast and easier to configure (as my use case, where I only need to process ~200 lines), but you are right that in bigger cases the usage of `awk` or `sed` is better.